# Iterating through the Keys of an object with a for...in Statement

Tags: javascript

Given this object and `for...in` statement, my expected output of `countOnline` is `false`. We are iterating and the online key for other object entries has been changed to the value 33. Why are we getting `true` back when we have a strict equality check for boolean?

```
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: true
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: 33
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: 33
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: 33
  }
};

function countOnline(usersObj) {

  for (let user in users) {
    if (users[user].online === true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

console.log(countOnline(users));
```

Comment: Alan has `online: true`, you are only checking, and if any has `true`, you return `true`.

Comment: But what about the other entries, those are supposed too be checked to in the for...in. Once we return program stops - had this before and don't understand why. I want to check Alan, Jeff, Sarah and Ryan. That is the point of the for..in

Comment: The function 'returns true' when the condition is met, rest of the iterations are ignored

Comment: Advice: use a debugger, step through the entire thing (it's really just four properties in the object, and a few lines of code), see what's happening, learn for life (that debuggers are a great tool).

Comment: This code has a few issues (unrelated to your question): 1. when you `return` from a for-loop, you'll iterate only one item. 2. object is unordered (you shouldn't expect the users to be iterated in the same "order" you defined them).

Comment: @user1554264 ```online: true ``` and other question answer is its return on the first iteration of object

Answer (score 1):

The first element in your array has `online: true`, and your function returns when it finds a user with `online: true`... so it just stops the loop and returns with true on the first iteration :)

Comment: Got it thanks, console.log() if I want to see the iterations. Return of course halts that.

Comment: @user1554264 haha yeah I was trying to figure out what you wanted to do there